# Can't manipulate subview properties after it has been added to superview - iOS Swift

Tags: ios, subview, uiactivityindicatorview

I'm trying to add a `UIActivityIndicatorView` to a button. The problem is, once the activity indicator view is added as a subview, I can no longer do anything with it. Here's my code below:

```
saveAiv = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 10, width: 20, height: 20))
saveAiv.color = .white
saveAiv.startAnimating()
saveAiv.isHidden = false
startQuizButton.addSubview(saveAiv)
self.view.addSubview(startQuizButton)
```

If I call `startAnimating()` and set `isHidden` before the subview is added, it works, but if I try to do anything with the activity view after it's added it has no effect. What is going on here?

Comment: Does the `UIActivityIndicatorView` appear when you add it as a subview to the button?

Comment: Only if I add it to the button before the button has been added to the view.

Comment: Show more code.. where you add the button to the view etc... if possible add both versions. One which works and the one that doesn't